# Error con la creación de menús dinámicos en Php con POO

Tags: php, mysql

Cordial saludo equipo, espero se encuentren bien, quiero pedirles el favor si me pueden colaborar con lo siguiente:

Tengo un archivo de conexión con nombre database.php:

```
<?php
class Database{

private $host;
private $db;
private $usuario;
private $contrasena;
private $charset;

public function __construct(){

  $this->host='localhost:3306';
     $this->db='grupo4s';
     $this->usuario='root';
     $this->contrasena='';
     $this->charset='utf8mb4';
}

function connect(){
 try{
$connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db .";usuario=" . $this->usuario .";contraseña=" . $this->contrasena . ";charset=" . $this->charset;

  $options = [ 
     PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
   ];

$pdo= new PDO($connection,$this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $options);
return $pdo;
print_r('Conexion satisfactoria ' . $e->getMessage()); 
echo "Conexion satisfactoria.";
}catch(PDOException $e){
  print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
  echo "Error connection";
}
}
}
?>
```

En el archivo Admin.php, lo que se realiza es tanto manejar privilegios de usuario, así como
imprimir unos menús dinámicos de acuerdo al privilegio o rol que tenga un usuario registrado:

Admin.php:

```
<?php   
require_once('Conexion/database.php');
session_start();
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE rol_id=1",$connection);
$row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
?>
<div style="text-align: right">
<?php  echo 'Usuario: '.$_SESSION['usuario']; ?>
</div>
 <?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['rol'])|| $_SESSION['rol'] != 1){
     header('location: index.php');
exit;
  }
?>
<html lang="en"> 
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Menú Administrador de la aplicación</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">  <!-- Ojo poner a todos los firmularios para que tomen estilos.css,antes estaba href="css/config1.css"-->
  <!-- ojo css/estilos.css, esta programado para que tenga una buena apariencia de cuadros grises con barra de menu azul  -->
  <div style="text-align: right">
   <a href="Conexion/cerrar_conexion.php">Cerrar conexión</a>
  </div> 
   <style>
   li{
      width: calc(100%/ <?php echo $row_cnt;?>);  //$row para el espacio entre campos
   }
</style>
</head>      
<body>
   <div id="contenedor">   <!--contenedor es un segmento de código de estilos.css -->
  <header>
  <h1 align="center">Administador</h1>
  </header>
  <nav>
  <ul>
   <?php
  
    //while($fila= mysqli_fetch_array($result)) //estructurado
  while($fila= $result->fetch_array($result))  
   { 
      echo '<li><a href="#">'. $fila['nombremenu'] . '</a></li>'; 
    }
   ?>
 </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo anterior lo realice con base al siguiente video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARoQow2UJyQ&t=791s

Los errores que me muestra son los siguientes:
Aviso: Variable indefinida: mysqli y error fatal: Error no detectado: llamada a una función miembro query () en nulo,
en la siguiente línea de código
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE rol_id=1",$connection);

esta linea de codigo proviene del archivo  admin.php.
Muchas gracias por la colaboración

Comment: donde declaras la variable $mysqli ? en la vista que compartes

Comment: intenta antes de usar la variable $mysqli, esto require_once('Conexion/database.php');
session_start(); $mysqli =  new Database();

Comment: Hola Leonel, en el archivo Admin.php, debajo del session_start();                                                                                          
$mysqli=new Database();                                                                            
pero me muestra el siguiente error                                                                        
Call to undefined method Database::query()  en la siguiente linea de código: $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE rol_id=1",$connection);

Comment: creo que el problema es que retornas el valor dese el constructor.

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto en tu clase de Database

```
    <?php
    class Database{
    
    private $host;
    private $db;
    private $usuario;
    private $contrasena;
    private $charset;
    private $pdo; // guarda la instancia creada de new pdo
    
    public function __construct(){
    
      $this->host='localhost:3306';
         $this->db='grupo4s';
         $this->usuario='root';
         $this->contrasena='';
         $this->charset='utf8mb4';
         $this->connect();
    }
    
    private function connect(){
     try{
    $connection = "mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db .";usuario=" . $this->usuario .";contraseña=" . $this->contrasena . ";charset=" . $this->charset;
    
      $options = [ 
         PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
         PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
       ];
    $this->pdo = new PDO($connection,$this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $options);
    //return $pdo;
    print_r('Conexion satisfactoria ' . $e->getMessage()); 
    echo "Conexion satisfactoria.";
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      print_r('Error connection: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
      echo "Error connection";
    }
    }
// recupera la instancia, del pdo. ya que este no sera visible. entonces es necesario un metodo para recuperarlo
     public function getConnection(){
      return $this->pdo;
     }
    }
    ?>
```

// admin.php

```
<?php

require_once('Conexion/database.php');
session_start();
$mysqli =  new Database();

$result=$mysqli->getConnection()->query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE rol_id=1",$connection);

........
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Leonel espero se encuentre bien ya arregle el inconveniente que tenia , pero me muestra los siguientes errores: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\Conexion\database.php on line 34 Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in 
 C:\wamp64\www\Grupo4sas\index.php on line 28

Comment: El código de la linea 28 es:       $query=$db->connect()->prepare('SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario=:usuario AND contrasena=:contrasena');
y el de la linea 34 es: $this->$pdo= new PDO($connection,$this->usuario, $this->contrasena, $options);